# Link opens page with modal active

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, url, bootstrap-modal

I have searched without much success, I have a "clients" page with ~60 clients listen. Each one has a unique modal that opens up with more information and details. What I would like is to reference some of the top clients on the home page with a link to open the clients page with modal already open. This was a project I took over so the js file is a bit of a rat's nest to dig through. Hoping there's a simpler answer.

Link Div

```
<pre class="default prettyprint prettyprinted">
   <code> 
      <span class="tag">&lt;a href="#champion2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#champion2" class="item-img-overlay"></span> 
   </code>
</pre>
```

Modal Id

```
<pre class="default prettyprint prettyprinted">
   <code> 
      <span class="tag">&lt;div class="modal fade" id="champion2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
   </code>
</pre>
```

Please help with any js or way I should link the separate URL to have these open when lined.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with some help. I had another hash filter so needed to work around that.  code is

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var isClientModalRequest = hash.indexOf('client') > -1;

    if (!isClientModalRequest)
        return;

    var client = hash.split('=')[1];
    var element = $('#' + client);

    element.modal('show');
    element.css('display', 'block');
    element.addClass('in');
});
```